# Factorial function in x86 NASM assembly goes wrong

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, x86, nasm, factorial

I'm learning assembly language using x86 NASM. I wanted to write a simple recursive factorial function to which I am passing one parameter using EAX register. After that, I want to print my result on the screen but nothing happens. After sitting and staring on my computer I don't have any clue what is wrong with my code. Can you guys help newbie with this problem?

I know that the prologue and epilogue of factorial funtion is not required due I'm not using stack but for me code is more readable ;)

Here is my code:

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
    message db "%03X", 0x10, 0x0

section .text
main:
    mov eax, 5
    call factorial
    push eax
    push message
    call printf
    add esp, 0x8
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

factorial:
    push ebp
    push edx
    mov ebp, esp
    mov edx, eax
    cmp edx, 0
    jne not_equal_zero
    mov eax, 1
    jmp exit
not_equal_zero:
    mov eax, edx
    sub eax, 1
    call factorial
    imul eax, edx
exit:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop edx
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Does it print 5 if you comment out your 'call factorial' in main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C library - I guess you use the one from GCC - doesn't output the result of `printf` immediately. Rather, it is stored in a separate memory called buffer and outputted by chance. In this case the program will be ended by `int 0x80/eax=1` faster than the buffer will be flushed. You can insert a manual flush:

```
...
extern fflush
...
push 0
call fflush
add esp, 4
...
```

The best solution is to use the C `exit` function. Replace

```
mov ebx,0
mov eax,1
int 0x80
```

by

```
push 0
call exit
```

or replace it simply by

```
ret
```

In this case you don't need to flush the buffer manually. This will `exit` or `ret` do for you.

BTW: LF (line feed) is coded as 10 **decimal** and 0x0A hexadecimal.

Comment: stdout *is* line buffered on a terminal, so it will output immediately (unless redirecting to a file or pipe), once the OP fixes the `"%03X", 0x10` newline bug.  But yes, mixing `printf` and `sys_exit` without fflush is a bug.